# How to get pydoc command working in Windows?

Tags: python, command-line, command, pydoc

`pydoc` does not work in Windows. at this post [Pydoc is not working (Windows XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391998/pydoc-is-not-working-windows-xp) the last answer by dave webb says to create a **pydoc.bat** file with this code in it:

```
@python c:\Python27\Lib\pydoc.py %*
```

After I create pydoc.bat where should it be placed so the `pydoc` command works in the command prompt?

*PS* adding `C:\python27\Lib\pydoc.py` to the Windows path in the system environment variables does not work. Even after logging out and back in it does not work.

Comment: If you double click on a `*.py` file in Windows Explorer does it start running or is something else happening, e.g. the file is opened in an editor? Also as far as I can see, this question has been already answered. Maybe you should comment over there if you're not happy with those answers.

Comment: a command prompt style window pops up for a fraction of a second and disappears when i double click a *.py file. i have not seen this question answered over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391998/pydoc-is-not-working-windows-xp but I will comment there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> PS adding C:\python27\Lib\pydoc.py to the Windows path in the system environment variables does not work. Even after logging out and back in it does not work.

The `PATH` environment variable is a list of *directories* to search for a given executable.  So you should be adding `C:\python27\Lib` to your `PATH` (not including the *filename*).

As for the `pydoc.bat` file you've created, one place to put it would be the `C:\python27\Scripts` directory which is usually added to your `PATH` by the python installation (since that folder contains miscellaneous scripts that you might like available at the command line).

Comment: the only Scripts folder I found is in C:\python27\Tools\Scripts. is this the same one you are referring to?

Comment: That sounds right -- I have python 2.5, so it may have changed.  That should probably be in your path already, or you can put it there if it isn't.

Comment: it worked but to get it to work I had to place pydoc.bat in C:\python27\Tools\Scripts not C:\python27\Scripts cause that DIR doesn't exist for me. thanks :)

Answer (score 29):

Use `python -m pydoc os` instead of `pydoc` directly, no need to add to path variable.

the -m tells python that pydoc is a pre-built module in python and NOT a script (.py file) sitting in the current working folder.

See https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html for details

Comment: You can also start pydoc server with this command `python -m pydoc -p 8080`. Then go to http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 4):

I have found in windows 10 powershell...

Remember to access pydoc in windows, it's 
python -m pydoc.  If you want to access info on "file", add the word "file"
after. Like this "python -m pydoc file" (*w/o the quotes).

What 
you type after python -m pydoc, will tell it what info you want brought up
and/or looking for.  i.e. python -m pydoc raw_input, python -m pydoc string, python -m pydoc file.

Remmeber python -m pydoc must be in front of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

put it in any folder that is in your PATH. Example: `C:\Windows\System32`

Alternatively, you can put it anywhere, and then add *the folder* it is in to windows PATH

Answer (score 1):

If you add .PY to your `PATHEXT` environment variable, you don't need the batch script. Just add `C:\Python27\Lib` to `PATH`, and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple PowerShell script sitting in my "\python27\" directory called 'pydoc.ps1'.  I can then call pydoc as intended...

ie.
c:> pydoc raw_input

code for 'pydoc.psi':

```
foreach ($i in $args)
    {python \python27\lib\pydoc.py $i}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example for Raw_input, try: python -m pydoc raw_input

Comment: The problem going by the accepted answer seems to be that the path environment variable needed to be updated.