# Calling pydoc in OSX - how do the links work, exactly?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pydoc

calling `pydoc file` is returning, `bad interpreter. no such file or directory.`

There's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391998/pydoc-is-not-working-windows-xp) by calling it like `python -m pydoc file`.

I would love to understand the way the links work better. For example what does the following do?

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc /usr/bin/pydoc
```

- which one is linking to which?

I'm running version 2.7 and pydoc exists in the /usr/bin/, as do pydoc2.5 and pydoc2.6. Same issue with python-config, which also exists in 2.5 and 2.6 versions.

Thanks a lot for any insight.

Here's how problem was solved, based on correct answer below:

- re-downloaded the python framework from http://andilabs.com/Python.framework.zip after finding it via [Python asks for older paths on mac after deleting duplicate python installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212270/python-asks-for-older-paths-on-mac-after-deleting-duplicate-python-installation?rq=1)
- made a backup copy of `pydoc2.7` by running `sudo mv pydoc2.7 pydoc 2.7-orig`
- copied the newly downloaded `pydoc2.7` to the framework version 2.7 bin using `sudo cp /Users/mikekilmer/Downloads/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc2.7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/`.

Apparently whatever i had under pydoc2.7 was not the right thing. Thanks a lot for explaining how links work!

Comment: `ln -s <source> <link>` creates a `<link>` that points to the `<source>`. In your example, the `ln -s` command creates a file `/usr/local/pydoc` that links to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc`.

Comment: @HuuNguyen - this comment should be an answer - you might want to expand it a bit.

Comment: thank you, @HuuNguyen. so i'm guessing that the `pydoc` i'm seeing in `/urs/bin/` is a link, and that pydoc simply doesn't exist in `/System/Library.../2.7/bin`. I'll see if I can find it and copy or move it there and post result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc /usr/bin/pydoc
```

Creates a link called `/usr/bin/pydoc` that points to:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc
```

On my system, this file doesn't exist. Instead, I have:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc2.7
```

Notice the `2.7` at the end.

So you've created a link to a file that doesn't exist and you get a complaint on your command line. The fix is simple, delete `/usr/bin/pydoc` (first make sure it is a link by typing `ls -l /usr/bin` and look for `pydoc` -- if it has an `l` next to its permissions, then it's a link). Then, type:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc2.7 /usr/bin/pydoc
```

This will create a link to the correct file and you should be able to run `pydoc` as a script now.

Comment: this is interesting. within `/usr/bin` is the link named `pydoc`. i removed it and made a link to pydoc2.7, but I'm still getting the error: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`, and within the directory, `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` there are `-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    123 Nov 10  2013 pydoc2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      6 May  1 11:39 pydoc -> pydoc2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      8 May  1 11:39 pydoc2 -> pydoc2.7`

Comment: wait.. that's odd. so removed the other `pydoc` links in `2.7 bin` so `pydoc2.7' is all that's left. after i create the link to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc2.7` using the above command, it seems like the link doesn't contain `/System` in the string.

Comment: okay never mind that train of thought. apparently unix starts the link string description from within the `System` folder. now getting error: `/usr/bin/pydoc: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`, when the pydoc link looks like this: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc2.7` and when i cd to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/`, there's `-rwxrwxr-x 1 root wheel date pydoc2.7`.